# How to focus client in Awesome WM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I have instance of the client which should be focused. I found only following ways to give focus to client:

- focus.bydirection (dir, c) - Focus a client by the given direction.
- focus.byidx (i, c) - Focus a client by its relative index.
- focus.filter (c) - Filter out window that we do not want handled by
- focus. focus.history.add (c) - Update client focus history.
- focus.history.delete (c) - Remove a client from the focus history.
- focus.history.get (screen, idx)  - Get the latest focused client for a
- screen in history.  focus.history.previous () - Focus the previous client in history.

But how to focus a client if I already have an instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try:

```
client.focus = c
c:raise()
```

`c` is the client which you want to focus.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Want to add one thing, which confused me. If you write a module, you have to duplicate all functions from the global namespace to the current one. Like `local client = client` or `local capi = {client = client, mouse = mouse, screen = screen, }`

Comment: (just start to use `awesome`) what's `client.focus`? Is it a global var? I can't find it in the `awesome` API

Comment: Check: http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/client.html - focus: The focused client.

Comment: @Shmygol Wanted to understand the reason why we have to duplicate all functions from the global to current?